# Assigning image brightness score with PIL need debugging

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to score an image in terms of its brightness quality, my code works well for full-color image, but when I am trying to use a transparent png, it throws an error saying ...r,g,b = stat.mean, too many values to unpack..., any tips or hints will be greatly appreciated.

here is my code:

```
def trim(im):
    bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, im.getpixel((0,0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    if bbox:
        return im.crop(bbox)

def brightness(stat):
    r,g,b = stat.mean
    brightness = math.sqrt(0.241 * (r ** 2) + 0.691 * (g ** 2) + 0.068 * (b ** 2))
    print 'perc brightness %s' % brightness
    return 1 - math.fabs(brightness / 100 - 1)

score_points = {
    'face': 120,
    'sat' : 50,
    'sharpness': 100,
    'bri': 50,
    'con': 100
}

filename = "tmp/thumb_2.png" 
im = Image.open(filename)

# crop all black borders
im = trim(im)

# check perceived brightness
v = ImageStat.Stat(im)
b = brightness(v) * score_points['bri']
print 'Brightness score: %s' % b
```

Comment: Obviously, ``stat.mean`` has something other than 3 values in this case.  Perhaps you could print it out and see what's actually there?  I'd guess that it has a fourth value, for the alpha channel of the image, in which you could fix the problem with ``r,g,b = stat.mean[:3]`` (but it would still break with a monochrome image).

Comment: @jasonharper, yes replacing r,g,b with r,g,b,a has fixed the problem. I forgot its png images got alpha channel as well. Thank you for your input and time.